# RavenDB attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ravendb

I'm playing around with RavenDB and deleted few test documents that had attachments before I had any attachments handling, so I was wandering if they are still on the disk somewhere and how I can find them *easily*?.

Another question is: When document is deleted and it had an attachment, will the attachment get auto deleted?

I have browsed through RavenDB Web UI (Server), but could not find attachments.

Just in case, below is my add attachment code:

```
_session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment(key, null, stream, optionalMetaData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by going to `http://localhost:8080/static` and look at the json result that comes back.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. Possibly ravendb has changed a bit since this answer was provided. If you're looking for attachments for a particular database , in raven 3.5, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380678/how-do-i-find-attachments-in-ravendb-3-5