# How do I find attachments in ravendb 3.5?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-http

I'm currently debugging some code which is supposed to return an attachment for a given document, but no attachment is coming back. Raven studio indicates that there are attachments in the database - it shows me that a number of attachments exist - but I can't see, via the studio web UI, if a particular document has an attachment.

Is there a way to query attachments via the studio UI? Also is there a way to tell if a document has an attachment via the studio UI? Online documentation don't seem to be clear on this. Alternatively is there a way to query ravendb using the http API for attachments?

I've tried the url suggested in [RavenDB attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302145/ravendb-attachments) but it returned an empty array as a response

Comment: Why not upgrade to RavenDB 4.2 ?

Comment: @Danielle the system is in the process of being upgraded from 3.5 to 4.2 but it's a gradual process so some data is still in 3.5

Answer (score 3):

`GET databases/{databaseName}/static/` will give you the list of attachments in the db.